Trying to set up CSOM with C# automatically produces an error
I am trying to link my C# code to my Microsoft List (aka, SharePoint List).    I believe this tech is called "CSOM". The learning path has included this suggestion:

It turns out I do, in fact, have Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll on local computer:


In my C# code, I have added these two DLL's as a Reference.  Then I typed in the "using" code as described. But when I tried to use this in my Visual Studio 2022 and I got this error:

What can I try next?

would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

You will need to add the SharePoint Client assemblies via the NuGet package manager to target the version of your project.
Go to NuGet package manager and search for CSOM then install the package to your project.

